# ldap 389 server with sssd client, cannot modify password

Tags: fedora, pam, ldap, sssd

I setup the 389 ldap server on a fedora system.  I can authenticate against the system, but I cannot update/modify a password neither as root nor as user.

- user root gets a "Password reset by root is not supported"
- a normal user gets  "Authentication token manipulation error"

I have now some clues from various forums, that I need to write an acl, which allows to modify the password, something with "self write".... I am neither sure if this only is valid for openldap and not 389, but maybe somebody here can give an answer how an acl would look like to enable passwd changes via ldap by normal users?

Comment: understood that password changes needs ssl/tls turned on, seems to be mandatory. After doing that and fixing some ssl related issues it works ;)